# Why "a means to" not "a mean to" nor "means to"?

Tags: grammar, difference

> He turned to substance abuse as a means to cope.

Is this something ungrammatical-but-they-use-it-everyday? Why don't they normally say like "as a mean to cope" nor "as means to cope"?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?  What do they say about the word *means*?

Comment: @Juhasz Oh you are right. I'm ashamed. Thank you.

Comment: No need to feel ashamed.  It's a reasonable question; it's just that we can't answer any better than a dictionary can.